# Twitter API Error: There were errors processing your request: Invalid json, could not parse

Tags: curl, twitter

Trying to pull tweets data into a JSON file but received the following error in the Terminal.

```
{
   "error": {
       "message": "There were errors processing your request: Invalid json, could not parse."
   }
}
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: Could you show the full code that you used to make the request? e.g. the cURL command